# How can I give skew shadow to this image?

Tags: jquery, css

Please have a look at the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiNHm.png)

[image]

I tried below code. But this is not even close.

```
    z-index: -1;
content: "";
box-shadow: 86px 0 17px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
-webkit-transform: skew(-36deg);
-moz-transform: skew(-36deg);
-ms-transform: skew(-36deg);
-o-transform: skew(-36deg);
transform: skew(-36deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
-moz-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
-ms-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
-o-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
transform-origin: 0% 100%;
```

Have a look at the second picture please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SpNr.png)

[image]
I would really appreciate if someone could help me there.

Thanks

Comment: Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a coding service, and you have to show us what you have tried yourself

Comment: okay, i am updating my post

Answer (score 0):

Use a `pseudo element` and rotate it give a shadow effect. Check this snippet.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 120px;
}
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
.image-wrapper:before{
   z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 120px;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  transform-origin: 70% 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.petsworld.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/cat.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
```